# Multipeer Connectivity Not working when connecting to adhoc network

Tags: multipeer-connectivity

We are developing an app that uses an adhoc connection between iOS and OSX. Unfortunately we are not able to connect the both devices in a peer to peer connectivity using an adhoc network, while properly works on infrastructure wifi. we check the connection in OS X Yosemite and it work perfectly in both network. On OS X El Capitan and higher version it's not working.Please do post your valuable suggestions. the below given is the sample project for both iOS and OSX.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7_E-xOVon9IZjFNWmRGazRnbFE?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case MultiPeerConnectivity not work on adhoc network in higher os like  OS X El Capitan and macOS Sierra. I use CFNetwork for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to setup an adhoc network on iOS, but my testing and talking with others suggests that MultiPeerConnectivity establishes links between applications over **pre-existing** link level connectivity.  If you want something more sophisticated, I suggest you look into FireChat's [MeshKit SDK](http://www.opengarden.com/meshkit.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information Eliot. In my case I need to transfer data between iOS and osx app. In meshkit they only said about iOS and Android.